# Find unique common element from 3 arrays

Tags: algorithm

**Original Problem:** 
I have 3 boxes each containing 200 coins, given that there is only one person who has made calls from all of the three boxes and thus there is one coin in each box which has same fingerprints and rest of all coins have different fingerprints. You have to find the coin which contains same fingerprint from all of the 3 boxes. So that we can find the fingerprint of the person who has made call from all of the 3 boxes.

**Converted problem:** 
You have 3 arrays containing 200 integers each. Given that there is one and only one common element in these 3 arrays. Find the common element.
*Please consider solving this for other than trivial O(1) space and O(n^3) time.*

Comment: Can you please clarify if one of the arrays can have repeating elements or not? For example, can you have `A = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}; B = {2, 3, 4, 5, 1}; C = {2, 2, 2, 2, 1};`?

Comment: Please read the qn carefully.

Comment: Also, you say there is only one common element in the three arrays. Does that mean only one element appears in all three arrays and just two of the three arrays can have other common elements, or can two of three arrays have no other common elements than the one that is common in all three?

Comment: @Rajendra: I have read it carefully, and both the original problem and the converted problem can be interpreted in multiple ways. Is it that hard to give a yes or no answer?

Comment: @|\/|ad
Right you are... But consider converted problem as the exact question and the easy answer to your question is NO, as it clearly says "Given that there is one and only one common element in these 3 arrays." Are you fine now? Can you think of an Aha! solution now?

Comment: @Rajendra thank you for the answer, that makes the problem very easy. However, I still think you're seeing things that are not there. "Given that there is one and only one common element in these 3 arrays" means that there is A SINGLE ELEMENT THAT APPEARS **IN ALL 3**. It doesn't say anything about an element not being able to appear in just two of the three arrays or about an element not being able to appear 199 times in a single array. But anyway, my solution ignores that and just takes your "NO" answer into consideration. Good luck in the interview.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Some improvement in Pelkonen's answer:**
From converted problem in OP:

*"Given that there is one and only one common element in these 3 arrays."*

We need to sort only 2 arrays and find common element.

Comment: +1 you need to iterate over all of 1 array anyway so you don't need to sort that one

Comment: It is possible that array A and B share common elements (a, b); array B and array C share common elements (b, c). Put together, array A, B and C share common element b. Therefore, to sort only 2 arrays is not sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

If you sort all the arrays first O(n log n) then it will be pretty easy to find the common element in less than O(n^3) time. You can for example use binary search after sorting them.

Comment: Or just merge sort them into one big array and check for a triplicate entry.

Comment: Answering my own comment : The original problem does not allow duplicates, but the converted problem does not say anything about uniqueness of the integers

Comment: You don't actually merge them, you just use a merge sort-like algorithm and have it stop when all 3 inputs have the same value.

Answer (score 3):

Let N = 200, k = 3,

1. Create a hash table H with capacity ≥ Nk.
2. For each element X in array 1, set H[X] to 1.
3. For each element Y in array 2, if Y is in H *and* H[Y] == 1, set H[Y] = 2.
4. For each element Z in array 3, if Z is in H *and* H[Z] == 2, return Z.
5. `throw new InvalidDataGivenByInterviewerException();`

O(Nk) time, O(Nk) space complexity.

Answer (score 2):

Use a hash table for each integer and encode the entries such that you know which array it's coming from - then check for the slot which has entries from all 3 arrays. *O(n)*

Answer (score 2):

Use a hashtable mapping objects to frequency counts. Iterate through all three lists, incrementing occurrence counts in the hashtable, until you encounter one with an occurrence count of 3. This is O(n), since no sorting is required. Example in Python:

```
def find_duplicates(*lists):
  num_lists = len(lists)
  counts = {}
  for l in lists:
    for i in l:
      counts[i] = counts.get(i, 0) + 1
      if counts[i] == num_lists:
        return i
```

Or an equivalent, using sets:

```
def find_duplicates(*lists):
  intersection = set(lists[0])
  for l in lists[1:]:
    intersection = intersection.intersect(set(l))
  return intersection.pop()
```

Comment: +1: I was going to suggest something similar.  You beat me to it!

Answer (score 1):

O(N) solution: use a hash table. H[i] = list of all integers in the three arrays that map to i.

For all H[i] > 1 check if three of its values are the same. If yes, you have your solution. You can do this check with the naive solution even, it should still be very fast, or you can sort those H[i] and then it becomes trivial.

If your numbers are relatively small, you can use H[i] = k if i appears k times in the three arrays, then the solution is the i for which H[i] = 3. If your numbers are huge, use a hash table though.

You can extend this to work even if you can have elements that can be common to only two arrays and also if you can have elements repeating elements in one of the arrays. It just becomes a bit more complicated, but you should be able to figure it out on your own.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the fastest* answer:

- Sort one array--time is N log N.
- For each element in the second array, search the first.  If you find it, add 1 to a companion array; otherwise add 0--time is N log N, using N space.
- For each non-zero count, copy the corresponding entry into the temporary array, compacting it so it's still sorted--time is N.
- For each element in the third array, search the temporary array; when you find a hit, stop.  Time is less than N log N.

Here's code in Scala that illustrates this:

```
import java.util.Arrays

val a = Array(1,5,2,3,14,1,7)
val b = Array(3,9,14,4,2,2,4)
val c = Array(1,9,11,6,8,3,1)

Arrays.sort(a)
val count = new Array[Int](a.length)
for (i <- 0 until b.length) {
  val j =Arrays.binarySearch(a,b(i))
  if (j >= 0) count(j) += 1
}
var n = 0
for (i <- 0 until count.length) if (count(i)>0) { count(n) = a(i); n+= 1 }
for (i <- 0 until c.length) {
  if (Arrays.binarySearch(count,0,n,c(i))>=0) println(c(i))
}
```

With slightly more complexity, you can either use no extra space at the cost of being even more destructive of your original arrays, or you can avoid touching your original arrays at all at the cost of another N space.

---

Edit: * as the comments have pointed out, hash tables are faster for non-perverse inputs.  This is "fastest worst case".  The worst case may not be so unlikely unless you use a really good hashing algorithm, which may well eat up more time than your sort.  For example, if you multiply all your values by 2^16, the trivial hashing (i.e. just use the bitmasked integer as an index) will collide every time on lists shorter than 64k....

Comment: How is this faster than a hashtable solution?

Comment: @lVlad: You can not guarantee, that the hashtable lookup is O(1). Depending on the hashfunction, how the impl. handles collisions and the actual input, then your performance might deterioate to O(n).

Comment: @Mads Ravn: true, you cannot guarantee, but you can get very very close to a guarantee considering what this problem actually asks for. Read the comments to the OP's post. Under those restrictions, forcing a hash function to go into worst-case mode would be pretty difficult I think.

Comment: @lVlad: You are right. If the integers are either distinct (except for the the one we're searching for) or chosen from a large set of potential numbers with uniform prob., then it indeed would be very hard to imagine a "realistic" hash table impl. deterioating. I just have the nasty habit of thinking theoretical worst-case whenever I see a big Oh - damn you CLRS :) As an aside a CS professor once, tongue in cheek, told me: "If you want your programs to perform well in practice, then you use a hash table. If you want your programs to perform well in theory, then you use a balanced tree".

Comment: Fastest worst-case solution, I meant (assuming the sort is done with mergesort or the like).  I agree that a hashtable can be faster, especially when memory is no issue.

Answer (score 0):

//Begineers Code using Binary Search that's pretty Easy

```
// bool BS(int arr[],int low,int high,int target)
// {
//     if(low>high)
//     return false;
    
//     int mid=low+(high-low)/2;
    
//     if(target==arr[mid])
//     return 1;
    
//     else if(target<arr[mid])
//     BS(arr,low,mid-1,target);
    
//     else
//     BS(arr,mid+1,high,target);
// }
//   vector <int> commonElements (int A[], int B[], int C[], int n1, int n2, int n3)
//     {
//         vector<int> ans;
//         for(int i=0;i<n2;i++)
//         {
//             if(i>0)
//             {
//                 if(B[i-1]==B[i])
//                 continue;
//             }
//             //The above if block is to remove duplicates
//             //In the below code we are searching an element form array B in both the arrays A and B;
//             if(BS(A,0,n1-1,B[i]) && BS(C,0,n3-1,B[i]))
//             {
//                 ans.push_back(B[i]);
//             }
        
//         }
//         return ans;
//     }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).